# nested field search in elastic search for structured data

Tags: search, elasticsearch, highlighting

I have a field named **"data"** . The **"data"** field gets populated with structured data dynamically. We do not have any **prior FIXED structure** for the Structured data. The data field contains data of type's **String, Date, Integer etc..**

example of structured data is

```
"data":
{
   {
    "fname":"ravinder",
    "lastname":"reddy",
    "join":"2009-11-15T14:12:12"
     "address""
      {
       "Hno": "253",
       "Street" : "james Street"
      } 
   }
}
```

***How do I search for a specific text in that data field ?***

I should be able to search for any text inside the data field and highlight that selected text.

**I used a pattern like data.* inside the search . But as the data field has many types of data. I am getting parsing Exceptions at runtime and all the shards failed to return anything.**

my query looks like below :

```
{
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "james street",
    "fields": [
      "data",
      "data.*"
    ],
    "type": {"phrase_prefix"}
  },
  "highlight":
   {
    "fields":{"data","data.*"}
   }
}
```

I can make this work if I replace **"data", "data.*" with "_all"**. But I am **unable to highlight** the fields.

Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an attempt, maybe it gets you started and you can experiment further:

```
DELETE /test
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "data_template": {
            "match": "data",
            "mapping": {
              "copy_to": "my_custom_all_field",
              "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
              "store": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "inner_fields_of_data_template": {
            "path_match": "data.*",
            "mapping": {
              "copy_to": "my_custom_all_field",
              "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
              "store": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "my_custom_all_field": {
          "type": "string",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/test/1
{
  "data": {
    "fname": "ravinder",
    "lastname": "reddy",
    "join": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "address": {
      "Hno": "253",
      "Street": "james Street"
    }
  }
}

POST /test/test/2
{
  "data": {
    "fname": "ravinder",
    "lastname": "james",
    "address": {
      "Hno": "253",
      "Street": "whatever Street"
    },
    "age": 55
  }
}

POST /test/test/3
{
  "data": {
    "fname": "mui",
    "lastname": "reddy",
    "address": {
      "Hno": "253",
      "Street": "james Street"
    },
    "age": 253
  }
}

GET test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "james street",
      "fields": [
        "my_custom_all_field"
      ],
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "data.*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

And for the example above, you get this kind of output:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.53423846,
        "_source": {
           "data": {
              "fname": "mui",
              "lastname": "reddy",
              "address": {
                 "Hno": "253",
                 "Street": "james Street"
              },
              "age": 253
           }
        },
        "highlight": {
           "data.address.Street": [
              "<em>james Street</em>"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.4451987,
        "_source": {
           "data": {
              "fname": "ravinder",
              "lastname": "reddy",
              "join": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
              "address": {
                 "Hno": "253",
                 "Street": "james Street"
              }
           }
        },
        "highlight": {
           "data.address.Street": [
              "<em>james Street</em>"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```